# Are there any projects using a temporary license similar to Founders Copyright?

Tags: licensing, relicensing

There is the [Founders Copyright](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Founders_Copyright) project that tried to adjust the copyright expiration time span to a much shorter time.

Is there something similar in software? As far as I understand, a project can release the source code and assets under a permissive license when the interest to the project starts fading so that the community can pick it up without problems, and it is not uncommon to do so. However, are there cases when this release is pre-announced initially and is a part of the license?

There is a similar question: 
[Is there a temporary copyleft license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5349/is-there-a-temporary-copyleft-license)

The difference is that I want to know about projects where something like this was actually applied ("shorter copyright time span"), not how to do it in general.

Answer (score 2):

As you can not give up your copy-right in many territories, there is the creative-commons-zero licence (similar to effect of public domain, but with legal fixes to make it work). (not all creative-commons licenses are Free / Open-source.)

Therefore stating that the software is GPL until a date, and then CC0. But this is a bit of a crayon wrapper, so lookout for something more general, and that has been checked.

What ever you choose, check that it deals with the expiration properly as the cc0 does.